# Is php5.6 still an accepted testing version in Github testing actions?

Tags: php, github, github-actions

I am using Github actions for the first time and using it to run automated tests on merge requests. I see that I can have it run tests on multiple PHP versions like so:

```
   strategy:
     matrix:
       php: [5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3]
```

However this fails with the error `php5.6: command not found`. It does the same for PHP7.0 but passes fine for 7.1, 7.2 and 7.3. I have searched as much as I can but I can't see any references to PHP5.6 or PHP7.0 not being available anymore so I am confused.

Can anyone shed some light on what may be happening?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the runner you're using. As you haven't specified which one you're using here is an overview of all the runners and the installed software: https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/software-installed-on-github-hosted-runners

F.e. Ubuntu 18.04 has the following PHP versions:

> - PHP 7.1 (PHP 7.1.33-16+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May 14 2020 08:27:11) ( NTS ))
> - PHP 7.2 (PHP 7.2.31-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May 14 2020 08:27:35) ( NTS ))
> - PHP 7.3 (PHP 7.3.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May 14 2020 10:34:44) ( NTS ))
> - PHP 7.4 (PHP 7.4.6 (cli) (built: May 14 2020 10:02:44) ( NTS ))